# Fast output text for WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, text, io

In my project I need to output large list of string to control that is similiar to windows notepad. Right now Im using TextBox.

```
  for(int i = 0; i< result.Count;i++)
 {
     textbox.Text += result[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
 }
```

If result count = 3000 then this loop lasts 13 second on my pc, this is definetely too slow, so what I should use(or how to configure Textbox?) for faster output?

Comment: What type is `result`?

Comment: `textbox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);`, no loop

Comment: You're replacing the text in the control 3,000 times. That's crazy. Just concatenate the strings once, and replace the control text once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a certain extent you are always going to take a performance hit if you are enumerating a very large collection. However, you can avoid a *lot* of string concatenation (which is very slow and memory intensive), and along with it having to assign the control text every iteration of your loop by using built-in string creation methods before assignment. An easy way in this case would be `String.Join`

```
textbox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Using a `StringBuilder` would also be more efficient:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i< result.Count;i++)
{
     builder.AppendLine(result[i]);
}
textbox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what I needed